# Disable Simple Product associated to configurable product when configurable product is disabled

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product

Just wondering how do I disable a simple product automatically when a configurable product is disabled?

Some times the products we have, we want to disable on our website however a configurable product has over 5-8 simple products associated to it. When I disable configurable product, simple product still stays enabled!

Any suggestion to make it automatically disable associated product?

Thanks

Comment: You can use mass edit to change status of all products at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Magento **event-observer**

> **catalog_product_save_after**

```
<catalog_product_save_after>
        <observers>
            <yourmodule>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                <method>catalog_product_save_after</method>
            </yourmodule>
        </observers>
</catalog_product_save_after>
```

in your observer

```
public function catalog_product_save_after($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    if( $product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::TYPE_CODE ){

        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            >getUsedProducts(null,$product);

        foreach($childProducts as $child) {
            $child->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
            $child->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick response. Basically you are suggesting for custome magento module, is that right? If so, could you please guide some more steps to achieve this. :)

Comment: I have created module for you find it on https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_7hBzRP1KDmTUN2dHNNcDVjTWc/view?usp=sharing